# Write text on image as display as image

Tags: php

I have one image in php like this

[image]

Now I want to write Number on white textfield at a run time.  And then I want to display it as a single image. How I can do this ?

I tried to search over and found different result but none of them worked for me.

I tried http://blog.doh.ms/2008/02/12/adding-text-to-images-in-real-time-with-php/

And this http://php.about.com/od/phpfunctions/g/imagestring_php.htm

It displays something like this that I didn't understand.

```
"‰PNG  IHDR‚2ª‘ËPLTEÿA£vIDAT(‘c`Ø?óþaà1@a“æmcŠ06 ‹cˆ$ngï1ÀPc 6çï†Ä=gŽ¥å²1ó60$n¸
‘cØÀØp.R!‚¡FhÎ±Â    sl€v5oøð¡Æ&ê    •@ÓÀI›Å1U•/LIEND®B`‚"
```

I am not sure why this is happening . Am I missing something ?

**UPDATE**

I did this

php opened

```
    $string = "BSThakrar";
    $image = ImageCreateFromJPEG("images/temp.jpg");
    $cor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

    imagestring($image,5,126,22,urldecode($string),$cor);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image,NULL,100);
```

php closed.

and it give this output
[image]

Comment: You can't overlay the text with css?

Comment: I find ironic the fact that you're asking advice about how to manipulate image... to print out a certificate for a course based on image manipulation.

Comment: No i can't overlay it because it works in simple html. But it automatically changes format when i send email to the user.

Comment: @STTLCU : it's just random image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = "BSThakrar";
$image = imageCreateFromJpeg("image.jpeg");
$cor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($image,5,126,22,urldecode($string),$cor);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image,NULL,100);
?>
```

It has to be a jpg image instead of a png you where trying, also $string can be replaced by the input you want it to have.

if you want to use a png, change to this:

```
<?php
$string = "BSThakrar";
$image = imageCreateFromPng("image.png");
$cor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($image,5,126,22,urldecode($string),$cor);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image,NULL);
?>
```

Comment: it gives many lines of output that i didn't understand. something like this "ØÿàJFIFÿþ-Ð§£Ü}—WÒgÔtK«ËKmSI»ÿE¾Òn™o¬IÑKm¯æ»Ç>=ýžÿko‡ß;þÈZÀÏ†_µ_„2Ó¼AðÏÂ_<eá]]ÿ…9àÚ‘ñOˆþø«DñEò&›Ž÷š³vk‘G¦¿7}-×q_}‰=tÞÿäQôWó§û~Ô¿´gŒÿjOÙcÃ´Ä/i~ ñìÍð "

Comment: Try again, I changed a string. Forgot to change imagejpg() function to imagepng :)

Comment: How can store image from this and display it in html.

Comment: and one other mistake you made is you took $image but using $rImg.

Comment: Did some changes again, can you check again? Working now at my server http://cloud.sportdirect.com/image.php using a png image.

Comment: yes it works on your server, i checked it. But i updated question with my code and output.will you please look at it and tell me if i am doing anything wrong ?

Comment: How i can store that image use it later in html ?

Comment: What if you load the php file in a <img> tag in html? And storing can be done with `imagejpeg($image, realpath('/folder/filename.jpg'));`