# Writing text on an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I need to add text to an already uploaded image and then upload the new image with the text back onto the server.

I'd like to use an image which is already on the server, which means that I have a variable `$image_location` linking directly to the image already set.

I found some code on StackOverflow which enables putting text on the image which you upload through the upload form.

My question is how would I change it so that instead of uploading the image, I could use the image already on my server.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
var
maxSize=600, // Max width or height of the image
font='italic small-caps bold 40px/50px arial', // font style
fontColor='white', // font color
textX=50, // text x position
textY=50, // text y position
h=function(e){
 var fr=new FileReader();
 fr.onload=function(e){
  var img=new Image();

  img.onload=function(){
   var r=maxSize/Math.max(this.width,this.height),
   w=Math.round(this.width*r),
   h=Math.round(this.height*r),
   c=document.createElement("canvas"),cc=c.getContext("2d");
   c.width=w;c.height=h;
   cc.drawImage(this,0,0,w,h);

   cc.font=font;
   cc.fillStyle=fontColor;
   cc.fillText(document.getElementById('t').value,textX,textY);

   this.src=c.toDataURL();
   document.body.appendChild(this);
  }
  img.src=e.target.result;
 }
 fr.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById('f').addEventListener('change',h,false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
1.write text
<input type="text" id="t">
2.add image
<input type="file" id="f">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, what have you tried in order to achieve this? Also, give http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a read.

Comment: If you want to use the image on the server you need to upload it first or use gd library and insert text in php.

Comment: Thanks, I 'll give it a read. So far i have tried changing img.src to a the image path and changing the input type to submit, but whatever I do is completly useless since sadly I'm a complete moron when it comes to javascript :S

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write text on image as display as image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003760/write-text-on-image-as-display-as-image)

Answer (score 0):

You can load an image to the canvas like so:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    c.width = img.width;
    c.height = img.height;
    cc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
img.src = '/path/to/image.jpg';
```

so it looks like the only thing you'd need to change is the `img.src` variable

Comment: Thank you, I have done that and then I 've changed the input type from "file" to "submit", after that it didn't work (the picture didn't appear). Now I'm asking how to show the image with submit instead of file. I asume it's somewhere in the script, but i tried most of the lines and I can't get it to work. I 'm really going to have to start studying this javascript asap.